# How to define compile time variable on Shared Code Project code

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, conditional-compilation

I'm currently working on adding some code to a project (XrmFakeEasy) that uses a Shared Code Project as main code repository .

I want to make changes to the following code paths :

```cs
#if FAKE_XRM_EASY_2016 || FAKE_XRM_EASY_365 || FAKE_XRM_EASY_9

            // Connect to the CRM web service using a connection string.
            CrmServiceClient client = new Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient(connectionString);
            return client;

#else
            CrmConnection crmConnection = CrmConnection.Parse(connectionString);
            OrganizationService service = new OrganizationService(crmConnection);
            return service;
#endif
```

Currently, the code between `#if FAKE_XRM_EASY_2016 || FAKE_XRM_EASY_365 || FAKE_XRM_EASY_9` and `#else` is greyed, and Intellisense/Debugging won't work on it.

Is there a way to get intellisense on the greyed code or to define the compile time variable on a shared code project ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get intellisense on the greyed code or to define the
>   compile time variable on a shared code project ?

**As far as I know**, it is designed by that and there is no such option to change it.

In such project, the current `if` condition is not valid(due to false condition) and is in the inactive area, which means that this part of the project will not be executed and therefore cannot obtain its Intellisense.

As a suggestion, you can try to assign a true condition to `#if`, in your situation, please first use this:

**1)** use this

```
#if true

////you can obtain the intellisense for this

#else 

.....

#endif
```

**2)** then change to this:

```
#if false

   .........

    #else 

    //////add your code here with the related Intellisense

    #endif
```

**3)** then change to this:

```
#if FAKE_XRM_EASY_2016 || FAKE_XRM_EASY_365 || FAKE_XRM_EASY_9

  .........
 #else 

  ........

 #endif
```